# ASP.NET MVC: Restricting access using url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, filtering

The URL for the administration section of my website always starts with `Admin/`. Is it possible in ASP.NET MVC to restrict access to users by using this part of the URL?

Obviously I would keep the `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` on appropriate controllers and actions but I wonder if it would be quicker for the application if it can just look at the URL instead of stepping into code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in Steven Sanderson's book, [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=Xb3a1xTSfZgC&pg=PA529&lpg=PA529&dq=ASP.NET+MVC:+Restricting+access+using+url&source=bl&ots=J9HbYav7ao&sig=aT3TSIBV8hVrlF1BHgdAbEsQBdI&hl=en&ei=jOieSoeeHYPQsQOq1O2PDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false).

Put the following code in your web.config file.

```
<location path ="Admin">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow roles="Administrator"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

This means for any URL matching `~/Admin/*`, the application will deny access to unauthenticated visitors or
any other visitors other than those with the role 'Administrator'.

Answer (score 1):

That will work but you then tie the authorisation to your current Routing model. The beauty of authorising the Actions is that it abstracts the functionality (which is, actually, what you want to control) from the url structure that you are currently using.

It also means that you can Unit Test this functionality.

Comment: So are there any advantages in using the URL for authorising?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a BaseAdminController, having all of your Admin Controllers extend this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class BaseAdminController : Controller {
}
```

Now, if you want it by URL, you did it correct already, but if you are just saving yourself from making sure it's on everything, above is the way. Then, you're tests can just make sure that all controllers in the Admin namespace extend this controller.